# Running ./Makefile in this git repo leads to errors

Tags: c, makefile

I cloned [this Github repo](https://github.com/SargisYonan/Choose-Your-Own-Adventure-Video-Game) to my Arch Linux machine. I ran `./Makefile` but get these errors.

```
./Makefile: line 9: MKFILE: command not found
./Makefile: line 10: DEPSFILE: command not found
./Makefile: line 11: GCC: command not found
./Makefile: line 12: CHEADER: command not found
./Makefile: line 13: CSOURCE: command not found
./Makefile: line 14: OBJECTS: command not found
./Makefile: line 15: EXECBIN: command not found
./Makefile: line 16: SOURCES: command not found
./Makefile: line 19: all: command not found
./Makefile: line 22: -o: command not found
./Makefile: line 24: fg: no job control
./Makefile: line 25: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
./Makefile: line 25: `  ${GCC} -c $<'
```

How do I actually run this program?

Answer (score 1):

`Makefile` is not a script file. It's designed to be run with `make`, not `sh` or `bash`. You should do instead:

```sh
make -f ./Makefile
```

Usually, however, you just do:

```sh
make
```

Some Makefile authors put a `#/usr/bin/make -f` shebang at the top of the file so that the file could be directly executed, but more often than not this is not the case.